# mysql 5.1 skip skip-networking param

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I don't know why my MySQL doesn't read the my.cnf file.
I wrote a commented line `# skip-networking` on my.cnf, restarted mysqld and when exec

```
#ps aux | grep mysql
```

returns:

```
root      7737  0.0  0.0   7184   812 pts/4    S+   12:20   0:00 grep mysql
root     14180  0.0  0.1  10764  1280 ?        S    Feb04   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
mysql    14293  0.3  3.7 396884 39364 ?        Sl   Feb04  15:27 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/####.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/####.pid
```

I understand the parameter --skip-networking could not be passed to MySQL if it is commented on my.cnf.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks and sorry for my English

Alvaro Canepa

Comment: What your install OS?

Comment: Is CentOS 5 with Plesk 9.6 (I don't know if it's relevant). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options; perhaps that directive is in the file more than once and you only commented one instance. Perhaps the startup command adds the directive, perhaps it's pulling from more than one config file.

Can you verify that the initscript is using the config file that you want it to, by changing another directive, restarting and checking whether your change takes effect? (perhaps using 'show global variables').

Then check your startup script (/etc/init.d/mysqld?) and then grep your entire config file(s) for the directive 'skip-networking'. Unfortunately, mysql doesn't tell you where a particular part of the runtime config came from. But it looks in /etc/my.cnf, /my.cnf and ./my.cnf, in that order, by default.